# About python programming. Can i change a function without redefining it?

Tags: python

first of all I am sorry for my bad English. in math in my language we call (for examle) f(x) = x**2  a function and research for the function is details about the function like what are the extreme points, what are the crossing points with the axis ... i dont know if these are the names for these things in English.

Any way.
I am trying to code a program in python that does a research on functions that the user decides.
so I need some help in two things:

1. I need to define a function from a user input for example if the user wants a research on the function `f(x) = x*\*2` I need to define a function `f = lambda x: x*\*2`
2. I need a way to solve equations without making the variable a symbol (SimPy).
   I have thaught about one way to do that. define another function that is the same function but the x is a symbol. The problem is that I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Can you provide an example of user input and expected output? Also `Sympy` fits your needs well enough, why can't you use it?

Comment: if the user wants to research a specific function for example f(x) = x^2 - 4 the input will be 'x**2 - 4' and i dont know how to define a function from that input. about the simpy, maybe it fits my needs but  I dont know how to use/ make it to fit my needs because I will need to solve equations like (from the example before) x^2 - 4 = 0 and to solve that equation i need to make x a symbol and if i do that i cant use the function. So about the input problem i have not got any idea but about the solving problem i have thought  about defining a function that is the same as the original (g = f)...

Comment: but now the problem is that I dont know how to make the x a symbol in the second function so that is why I asked for help at changing a function without redefining it.

Comment: Please provide an example of solving equations, I can't guess what exactly do you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can solve the first your question:

```
def create_function(user_input):
    return lambda x: eval(user_input)

user_input = input('enter function: ')
f = create_function(user_input)
print(f(10))
```

Example of usage:

```
enter function: x ** 2 - 4
96
```

Comment: Thank  you very much! very helpful!